# Swiping an UIView gradually XAMARIN IOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am doing a project where I can not use xamarin.forms or story board. I wanted to Swipe an UIView and make it disappear gradually (following my swiping, if you know what I am trying to say). I can do the swipe, I am using SwipeGesture, but how do I make this swipe animated? Slowly fading as I am swiping?

Code:

```
      UIView testeS = new UIView(new CGRect(0, 0, 5, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height));
            testeS.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
            Add(testeS);
            UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeRight = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(OnSwipeRight);
            swipeRight.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Right;
            testeS.AddGestureRecognizer(swipeRight);


            UISwipeGestureRecognizer swipeLeft = new UISwipeGestureRecognizer(OnSwipeLeft);
            swipeLeft.Direction = UISwipeGestureRecog



        private void OnSwipeRight()
        {
            Add(tab);
        }

        private void OnSwipeLeft()
        {
            tab.RemoveFromSuperview();
        }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if by "disappear" you mean fade away (Opacity/Alpha) or you want the view to change width until it disappears.

The Swipe gesture recognizer only senses if you do a swipe gesture, it cannot "follow" your touches. To do that, you need to subclass UIView and implement the touches methods, e.g. BeginTouches, etc. The UIView subclass below will watch the touch (single touch only, multi touch is not enabled on a view by default) and adjust the width of the view when the touch moves:

```
public class SwipeView : UIView
{
    nfloat initialTouchXLocation;
    CGRect initialFrame;

    public SwipeView(CGRect rect) : base(rect)
    {
        initialFrame = rect;
    }

    public override void TouchesBegan(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesBegan(touches, evt);

        initialTouchXLocation = touches.ToArray<UITouch>()[0].LocationInView(this).X;
    }

    public override void TouchesMoved(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesMoved(touches, evt);

        nfloat newTouchXLocation = touches.ToArray<UITouch>()[0].LocationInView(this).X;

        nfloat newWidth = (newTouchXLocation - initialTouchXLocation) + initialFrame.Width;
        if (newWidth < 5)
            newWidth = 5; // keeps the view from getting too narrow to touch
        Frame = new CGRect(initialFrame.X, initialFrame.Y, newWidth, initialFrame.Height);
    }

    public override void TouchesCancelled(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesCancelled(touches, evt);

        initialFrame = this.Frame;
    }

    public override void TouchesEnded(NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
    {
        base.TouchesEnded(touches, evt);

        initialFrame = this.Frame;
    }
}
```

Then just add this view instead of the stock UIView:

```
SwipeView testeS = new SwipeView(new CGRect(0, 0, 5, UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height));
testeS.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
Add(testeS);
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! That's exactly what I wanted!